# jpql object IN list without CriteriaBuilder

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, criteria, jpql

i have to get all `Invoice` where `Invoice.responsible` IN a list of `Usergroup`?

I tried following:

```
public List<Invoice> getOldestInvoiceWithOpenBenefits(List<Usergroup> usergroups) {

    TypedQuery<Invoice> q = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Invoice i WHERE (i.responsible IN (:usergroups)) AND "
            + " i.entered = false AND i.totalcosts > (SELECT SUM(b.costs) FROM Benefit b WHERE b.invoice = i) ORDER BY i.creationdate ASC",
            Invoice.class);
    q.setParameter("usergroups", usergroups);
    q.setMaxResults(10);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

but i alwasy get this error:

```
Information: /pages/index.xhtml
Warnung: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB InvoicEJB, method: public java.util.List de.ltg.sachzuwendungen.ejb.InvoicEJB.getOldestInvoiceWithOpenBenefits(java.util.List)
Warnung: javax.ejb.EJBException
    [...Stacktrace]
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6075] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Object comparisons can only use the equal() or notEqual() operators.  Other comparisons must be done through query keys or direct attribute level comparisons. 
Expression: [
Relation operator [ IN ]
   Query Key responsible
      Base de.ltg.sachzuwendungen.db.entity.Invoice
   Constant [
Parameter usergroups]]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.invalidOperatorForObjectComparison(QueryException.java:646)
[...Stacktrace]
```

Can someone help me to get this work without using the CriteriaBuilder?
If you need the database entities just ask.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

Invoice Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_invoice")
public class Invoice implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    /**
     * Optimistic Locking
     */
    private int version;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "number")
    private String number;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "totalcosts")
    private double totalcosts;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "issuedate")
    private Date issuedate;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "creationdate")
    private Date creationdate;
    @Column(name = "entered")
    private boolean entered;
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUser_creator", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User creator;
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUsergroup_responsible", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Usergroup responsible;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoice")
    private List<Benefit> benefits;

    public Invoice() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
/*Getter & Setter*/
..
/*Override toString()*/
..
}
```

Usergroup Entity:

> 

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_usergroup")
public class Usergroup implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    /**
     * Optimistic Locking
     */
    private int version;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Right.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "t_mapUsergroupToRight", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idUsergroup") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idRight") })
    private List<Right> rights;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "t_mapUserToUsergroup", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idUsergroup") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idUser") })
    private List<User> users;

    /*Getter & Setter*/
    ..
    /*Override toString() & equals() & hashCode()*/
    ..

   }
```

> 

Comment: Could you show us the `Invoice` entity?

Comment: i added them to the question

Comment: tried a different JPA implementation, to check whether it is specific to your provider ? I can do queries of that for on DataNucleus JPA with success.

Comment: What version of EclipseLink do you use? Is that JPA 2.0? It seems that beginning with JPA 2.0 there is support for collection-valued input parameters (in IN expressions). Have you tried to upgrade Eclipse?

Comment: Im using buildin eclipselink Version of
GlassFish Server 3.1.2
Full Platform, Details: https://glassfish.java.net/webprofileORfullplatform31x.html

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here `i.responsible IN (:usergroups)`. It should be `i.responsible IN :usergroups` (without paranthesis). Also keep in mind, that some JPA implementations throw Exceptions, if hte list is empty, so you should mind checking that.

Comment: i changed it to `"SELECT i FROM Invoice i WHERE (i.responsible IN usergroups) AND i.entered = false AND i.totalcosts > (SELECT SUM(b.costs) FROM Benefit b WHERE b.invoice = i) ORDER BY i.creationdate ASC"` but im still getting the same error

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT i FROM Invoice i WHERE i.responsible IN usergroups` alone?